# Can anyone tell me the value in this edit

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3828863/7

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3828863/revisions

I know it's my answer, but as always I'm happy for people to edit both my questions and answers to improve them.

I can't see any value in that edit. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any value in it either; it's just making something that has a code-like name and giving it emphasis `via code block` syntax.

Code blocks aren't meant for emphasis, people.  Go ahead and roll that edit back.  The value it adds is not there.

Comment: I thought `FidFirstFile` is function name... Could you please clarify at which point function name stop being code? (maybe name is not code, sample call is?)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  Be that as it may, it doesn't really add any *clarity* overall to the answer.  It's got a link to documentation and everything; that's about as clear as it needs to get.  It doesn't truly need the code block.

Comment: @Makoto: Do edits necessarily have to improve an answer's _clarity_? An edit could improve a post's aesthetics without changing how easy it is to read.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  I see it as the same thing.  An edit to a question can be done to both make it more intelligible as well as more pleasing to the eye to read.  Both of these points are what make the answer more clear.

Comment: While I disagree that the edit should be rolled back, I don't think it ever should have been made in the first place. Bumping a question this old just to format something so minor is a complete waste.

Comment: Who even uses the "Active" tab?

Answer (score 3):

Since `FindFirstFile` is a function name, the editor decided to format it as code.

Contrary to [@Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto)'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308071/1835379) here, I'm fine with that. The editor has the ability to edit posts without that edit requiring a review, so minor improvements like that can be made.

There's no harm in the edit, and it makes the post (arguably) more semantically correct.
I ***wouldn't roll it back***. Rolling back the edit *doesn't* make the post *better*. Even worse, it might spawn a discussion about the merits of such an edit, on that post.

That said, if this were a **suggested edit**, I'd have **rejected** it as too minor.

Comment: You make an excellent point here; if this were indeed a suggested edit, then it would have been entirely too minor.   Then again, I kind of feel like it's playing to a double-standard here; if the edit would be too minor for someone with less than 2K rep, who's to say that the edit isn't too minor for someone with more than that?  Could you strengthen the argument on it a bit?

Comment: @Makoto yes, the edit is minor and we should not be spending time discussing it :)  But that is the value of 2K+ editors - make small changes that improve posts (even margianlly) and since there are no other people involved (except sometimes OP) the only time and effort spent are of the editor.

Comment: I couldn't have explained the difference better, @AlexeiLevenkov.